# On stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/company URLs, the sidebar shifts down

Tags: bug, design, left-navigation, companies-page

On a stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/company URL (for example https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies/google), the sidebar shifts down a little. I am using Google Chrome 83.0.4103.61 (Official Build) (64-bit) on macOS Version 10.15.5 (Build 19F96)

[image: Image of bug]

Normal page:

[image]

Comment: Does this happen in light mode?

Comment: It does. Just in case this is a browser specific issue, I am using Google Chrome 83.0.4103.61 (Official Build) (64-bit) on macOS Version 10.15.5 (Build 19F96)

Comment: @GalaxyCat105 I would put the OS and Browser info into the question itself so it isn't lost in comments